# How can I save the content of tinyMCE before destruction? (close tab, navigate etc.)

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-5

We have a webpage which has a tinyMCE editor tied to a DB. In this webpage we have some buttons like „Help”, „Settings”, „Logout” which can 'erase' (let's use this terminology) the content of our tinyMCE editor, because these buttons open another layout(s) in which, of course, the editor is absent.

We want to trigger our „Save to Db” subsystem when the user:

1. Clicks anyone of buttons which destroy the editor (see above)
2. Destroy the tinyMCE editor by closing the tab / browser.
3. Destroy the tinyMCE editor by navigating somewhere else (eg. from ourSite.com to google.com)

Now we tested all the above and (of course) the content isn't saved.

How can we achieve this automatic save on destroy?

The solution must work on Chrome/Edge, Firefox and Safari.

Notes:

- we tried this demo: https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/hRhaab/2 (hooking the „remove” event) but it doesn't seem to work.
- an alternative popup with „The data is not saved. Do you want to continue?” is also acceptable.
- the data is rather small. No images, just some text (few A4 pages at most).
- in the case of buttons, we try to avoid the obvious solution by writting a DoSaveMyEditor() under each button

Any help?

Comment: Have you tried to combine  the `editor.input` event on the host with a `window.onbeforeunload`? This would provide the popup/functionality that unsaved data can be lost.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize the TinyMCE [Autosave plugin](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/autosave/). It does the job by itself but saves the data to local storage. However, it can be identified by setting an [`autosave_prefix`](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/autosave/#autosave_prefix) and then taken out of the storage and uploaded to your DB.